# JAX-WS 2.1 validation error : cannot find SEI specified by the WS endpoint

Tags: java, web-services, deployment, websphere, jax-ws

I have enterprise aplication with JAX-WS 2.1 webservice. During application deployment on WAS (websphere application server) 8.0.0.0 (32-bit) this occurs :

```
2/17/12 14:46:38:857 CET 000004b8 WSModuleDescr E WSWS7027E:
**JAX-WS Service  Descriptions could not be correctly built because of the following error:
javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Validation error: cannot find SEI specified by the WebService.endpointInterface.**
Implementation class: com.dummy.ws.bean.impl.DummyWSManager; EndpointInterface: com.dummy.ws.bean.DummyWSManagerSei

EndpointEnabler configuration :
    verbose = true
    http.enableRouterSecurity = false
    dummy-ejb.http.contextRoot = /dummyrouter
    dummy-ejb.DummyWSManager.http.urlPattern = /DummyWSManager
```

**What could be wrong ?** This exception is quite rare, i need to know real reason for that problem. I am using similar applications also with JAX-WS and without any problems.

Comment: Are those two class files available? i.e. "com.dummy.ws.bean.impl.DummyWSManager" and "com.dummy.ws.bean.DummyWSManagerSei". Are they available in your WEB-INF/classes in the correct folder, or in a jar in WEB-INF/lib?

Answer (score 2):

Your Endpoint interface:

```
@javax.jws.WebService (endpointInterface="xyz")
```

is not pointing to its port.
Verify where exactly the port file is located and give a complete path of that file as your endpoint interface.